# Using If-Statement to assign Variable in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to create an awk script file that takes an input file and converts the fourth column of information for the first three lines into a single row.
For example, if input.txt looks like this:

```
XX YY val1 1234
XX YY val2 2345
XX YY val3 3456
stuff random garbage junk extrajunk
useless 343059 random3
```

I want to print the fourth column for rows 1, 2 and 3 into a single row:

```
1234 2345 3456
```

I was trying to do this by using if/else-if statements so my file looks like this right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    if ($1 == "XX" && $3 == "val1") 
    {
             var1=$4; 
    }  
    else if ($1 == "XX" && $3 == "val2") 
    {
             var2=$4; 
    }
    else if ($1 == "XX" && $3 == "val3") 
    {
             var3=$4; 
    }
}
```

END{
print var1,var2,var3

and then I would print the variables on one line. However, when I try to implement this, I get syntax errors pointing to the "=" symbol in the var2=$4 line.

*EDIT*

Solved, in my real file I had named the variables funky (yet descriptive) names and that was messing it all up. - Oops.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing your efforts in form of code(keep it up). But your question is NOT clear, its always recommended to add sample of input/output too in your question, so please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Is it as simple as to remind that you need `{  braces ...}` around those statements if they are in the main body of awk code? Otherwise you will get random syntax errors (random as in related to the version of awk...)

Comment: Post a minimal complete script that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: It was a simple mistake on my part in my real variable names! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write something like this

```
$ awk '$1=="XX"{if($3=="val1") var1=$4
                else if($3=="val2") var2=$4
                else if($3=="val3") var3=$4}
        // .. do something with the vars ....
```

however, if you just want to print the fourth column of the first 3 lines

```
$ awk '{printf "%s ", $4} NR==3{exit}' ile
1234 2345 3456
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/env bash
awk '
$1 == "XX" { var[$3] = $4 }
END { print var["val1"], var["val2"], var["val3"] }
' "$@"
```

There's almost certainly a much simpler solution depending on your real requirements though, e.g. maybe:

```
awk '
{ vars = (NR>1 ? vars OFS : "") $4 }
NR == 3 { print vars; exit }
' "$@"
```

. For ease of future enhancements if nothing else, don't call awk from a shebang, just call it explicitly.